# Using AWS CloudFront with S3 to server js and css files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have setup AWS CloudFront and S3 as it's origin.

I have made the files I want to access in the bucket public, but I am getting a 403 Forbidden error/Access denied XML when I try to access these files.

A link is simply:

http://dd9rhibbjdy7s.cloudfront.net/assets123/app.js

I have Googled everywhere but still can't find the solution.

Does any one have a clue how to get this working?

---

The exact response when browsing to it is:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>74E36027507DACD6</RequestId>
<HostId>
uUxkyTmpJbfxk1UJTf9bZmtkA/Vqq5O4eRruiG8zpC6uWn7tA1ffd5bnM4GcKD9Hp0BPKqKsBKQ=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Have you added a bucket policy to the S3 Bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Add this bucket policy to your S3 Bucket, remember to change the bucket name.

```
{
  "Version":"2008-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
         },
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you flush the cloudfront cache?

Comment: They're called invalidations - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

Comment: I created one for / assuming that's everything in the bucket to no effect :(

Comment: you need to specify each file you want to invalidate so: /assets123/app.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86833/discussion-between-stefan-and-imperium2335).

Comment: @stefan fwiw, CloudFront recently introduced wildcard invalidation, so `/*` (the entire distro) can now be invalidated.  https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/05/amazon-cloudfront-makes-it-easier-to-invalidate-multiple-objects/

Comment: Can you access it through s3 directly without cloudfront?

Comment: Yes I can access directly

Comment: Can you post the s3 URL?

Comment: Correction, I can not, was certain I could yesterday :s

Comment: Enable website hosting on the bucket and post the URL endpoint

Comment: This is the url i can access: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets123/app.css

Comment: Is that the url it showing as endpoint under static website hosting?

Comment: I can't enable static web because I have no endpoint file, I am just hosting my css and js for now, or want to at least.

Comment: The file doesn't need to exist just enter index.html and error.html

Comment: I'm getting 404 now as index doesn't exist, I can get to app.js, still no luck with the cloudfront url though.

Answer (score 0):

One of my collegues suggested I use the policy generator and came up with this:

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1439469599074",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1439469594186",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::assets123/*",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which has made it all work :)